# https servlet with Jetty

Tags: java, servlets, ssl, https, jetty

I wrote a simple https servlet with Jetty according to the documentation which for some reason does not work. No error messages, nothing... the browser connects to the servlet, but that's it - after the connection it hangs forever. Here is the code:

```
    SslSocketConnector sslConnector =  new SslSocketConnector();
    sslConnector.setPort(5555);
    sslConnector.setKeystore(null);
    sslConnector.setHost("localhost");
    ((AbstractConnector) connector).setThreadPool(new QueuedThreadPool(20));
    server.addConnector (sslConnector);


ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");

    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();

    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] {context, new DefaultHandler() });
    server.setHandler(handlers);

    MyServlet servlet = new MyServlet();
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(servlet), "/*");

    server.start();
    server.join();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sslConnector.setKeystore(null);

For an SSL connection you need to add a SSL certificate,which can be generated using tools provided in JDK.

See

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Security6.html

Comment: From Jetty documentation: keystore - The resource path to the keystore, or null for built in keystores.

Comment: Looks like it is a bug in Jetty documentation - it cannot be null after all, this "internal keystore", whatever that means, is either not working or does not exist